# Configure @Path("") and @Path("/") at the same time

Tags: java, jax-rs

I have these two resource methods. I want:

"...path/" matches #withRoot

"...path" matches #withoutRoot

```
@GET
@Path("/")
public void withRoot() {
    int x = 0;
}

@GET
@Path("")
public void withoutRoot() {
    int x = 0;
}
```

But currently it just jumps into #withRoot. How can I achieve this?

Comment: There is no difference between a path ending with `/` and one without, just like a file path

Comment: @Dummy Is there any solution to do this? My need is to return content under root "/" for #withRoot and do a query for #withoutRoot.

Comment: Your question doesn't make semantic sense when applying URL rules. If you explain your use case further, we may be able to come up with something. (If you need a "query",  perhaps you should be discriminating based on a query string.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible, as per the documentation found for Jersey:

> Likewise, by default, a @Path value may or may not end in a '/', it makes no difference, and thus request URLs that end or do not end in a '/' will both be matched.

So, separating the two does not make any sense in this case. And, why would you? If you want to represent two different paths, you will be better off by creating two different routes representing each of the functionality you're trying to expose.